# Default constructor constraints in Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I when I run the shown unit test I get an exception `Object does not match target type` during protobuf *deserialization*.

I narrowed the problem down to the default constructor `ContainerForA()`.

This default constructor initializes the variable `PropA` with an instance of `ClassA` during deserialization, as protobuf-net will call the default constructor. Afterwards the protobuf deserializer should overwrite this property with the serialized instance of `ClassB`. I think at this point the exception is thrown.

If I remove the code from the default constructor `ContainerForA()` the test seems to work.

Does protobuf-net have constraints on what you are allowed to do in your default constructor? Or is there any other problem with my code?

I am using `protobuf-net portable 2.0.0.668`

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(IBaseB))]
[ProtoInclude(102, typeof(ClassA))]
public interface IBaseA { }

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(103, typeof(ClassB))]
public interface IBaseB : IBaseA { }

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassA : IBaseA
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int PropA { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassB : IBaseB
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ContainerForA
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public IBaseA InstanceOfA { get; set; }

    public ContainerForA()
    {
        InstanceOfA = new ClassA();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ProtoTestBed1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProto()
    {
        var containerForA = new ContainerForA()
        {
            InstanceOfA = new ClassB { PropB = "I'm B"}
        };

        var proto = new ProtobufSerializer();
        var bytes = proto.Serialize(containerForA);
        var containerForADeserialized = proto.Deserialize<ContainerForA>(bytes);

        Debug.WriteLine(containerForADeserialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this `[ProtoInclude(103, typeof(ClassB))]` not be declared on `IBaseA`?

Comment: I am not quite sure, I couldn't find information on this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the constraints are (Mark will probably come along in a bit and tell you) but there are work arounds

Try this:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]
public class ContainerForA
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public IBaseA InstanceOfA { get; set; }

    public ContainerForA()
    {
        InstanceOfA = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

Had another look at this using the Portable version. Not sure how to do this using attributes but came up with the following solution which seemed to work by using a factory method to "undo" the constructor.

```
    public class ContainerForA
    {
        public IBaseA InstanceOfA { get; set; }

        public ContainerForA()
        {
            InstanceOfA = new ClassA();
        }

        private static ContainerForA EmptyContainerFactory()
        {
            return new ContainerForA()
            {
                InstanceOfA = null
            };
        }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containerForA = new ContainerForA()
        {
            InstanceOfA = new ClassB { PropB = "I'm B" }
        };

        var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
        var baseA = model.Add(typeof(IBaseA), true);
        baseA.AddSubType(101, typeof(IBaseB));
        baseA.AddSubType(102, typeof(ClassA));
        var baseB = model.Add(typeof(IBaseB), true);
        baseB.AddSubType(103, typeof(ClassB));
        var classA = model.Add(typeof(ClassA), true);
        classA.AddField(1, "PropA");
        var classB = model.Add(typeof(ClassB), true);
        classB.AddField(2, "PropB");
        var container = model.Add(typeof(ContainerForA), true);
        container.AddField(3, "InstanceOfA");

        container.SetFactory("EmptyContainerFactory");

        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        model.Serialize(mem, containerForA);
        mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var containerForADeserialized = model.Deserialize(mem, null, typeof(ContainerForA));

        Debug.WriteLine(containerForADeserialized);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about that! This attribute parameter is unfortunately not supported for the portable version of protobuf-net.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, Does the second work-around work for you?

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer. yes, it does! That issue looks like a bug to me, I will report it.

Answer (score 0):

The project maintainer Marc Gravell confirmed that this is intended behavior:

Protobuf-net prefers not to replace instances;

If a sub-object / collection / etc is non-null, it tries very hard to use it rather than reallocate everything in the tree.

In your case, the simplest fix is probably to simply **not** run the constructor during deserialization